# Tomcat / JBoss post deployment script

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss

Is there a way to execute a post deployment script in Tomcat / JBoss?

I want this script to execute when ever a new WAR file is deployed.

Also the war files will not know anything about the script, so I can not use Startup Servlets.

Comment: How are you deploying your app?

Comment: @Desorder I understand what you are asking, I should add the script to CI job that deploys the war file, however there are multiple CI jobs that deploy various apps I do not want to modify all of them. Also I want this to plugin app server than CI job.

Comment: Sweet. Not a problem... I think that would be your best bet as I never heard about a post deployment "event/listener" feature for Tomcat and/or JBoss. And I use those quite a bit.

Comment: @Desorder yes CI Job change is the last option, if no alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well a possibility on Jboss - standalone can be script that monitors changes to x.war.deploying to x.war.deployed or x.war.failed. That way you can have some control on when to execute.

Not sure if file change event on directory is helpful in your case, refer to following link for idea for linux
https://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes

Comment: I will need to know the war file name in advance for this, isn't it?

Comment: not really. if you do not know war file name you know its extension. Match pattern on wildcard.like \*.war.deploying.